# Can't call https request(self-signed certificate) in the Swift 5

Tags: node.js, swift, api, nginx, swift5

I can't send the request to https API.
You can access to https://13.48.109.132/api and can see the express site.
I use Nginx and you can check the configuration in here. Also, I only use IP address now not the domain name. As you can see in here Nginx config, I call my Node.js server hosted by pm2(Http, 9000 port) after a call the https://13.48.109.132/api. I realize it's working when I call in the web browser.

```
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

But I can't call this api in the swift 5.

```
var jsonResponse: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            do {
                if data != nil {
                    jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String: String]
                    taskCallback(true, jsonResponse as Dictionary<String, String>?)
                } else {
                    taskCallback(false, jsonResponse as Dictionary<String, String>?)
                }

            } catch {
                taskCallback(false, jsonResponse as Dictionary<String, String>?)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
```

And I can see the below error.

```
2019-07-23 00:47:25.957170+0800 Marvel[2464:869140] TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x281f2e4c0]: 3:0
2019-07-23 00:47:25.984462+0800 Marvel[2464:869140] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2019-07-23 00:47:25.984575+0800 Marvel[2464:869140] Task <AEBD09B5-023E-448D-8233-BFAC0A68B682>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9813])
2019-07-23 00:47:25.985082+0800 Marvel[2464:869205] Task <AEBD09B5-023E-448D-8233-BFAC0A68B682>.<1> finished with error - code: -1202
response Optional([:])
```

I check the stackoverflow articles and find info.plist configuration like this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

But it's not working.
Hope your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not correct

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
```

You should be setting a url

```
let URL_SERVICE = "https://13.48.109.132/api"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL_SERVICE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I receive url as a parameter in this function and also this works when I request http api.